# How can I test that a buildah script is run under buildah-unshare?

Tags: namespace, uid, unshare, gid, buildah

If I have a script that uses `buildah mount`. I use the same way the docs specify,

```
mnt=$(buildah mount $ctr)
```

If I invoke my script `sh ./build.sh`, I get

> cannot mount using driver overlay in rootless mode. You need to run it in a `buildah unshare` session

The problem is that the script doesn't terminate in the event of failure here. I can check it out by testing for `if [-z $mnt]; then echo "Run with buildah-unshare; exit; fi`, but this is not ideal because then I still have the prior `buildah from` that I'm doing for nothing.

If you're trying to support rootless buildah, is there a way to ensure that you're running the buildah under `buildah unshare`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to make sure that the root user is mapped to something. If you run `cat /proc/self/uid_map` on the main usernamespace, you'll see uid=0 is mapped to 0 for a length of all users `4294967295`. This is a dummy mapping (see `man namespaces` for more information).

```
$ cat /proc/self/uid_map
0          0 4294967295
```

If that dummy mapping is **NOT** in that file, you're in a child user namespace.

```
# If we find the dummy line, error and exit
grep -lE '^\s+0\s+0' /proc/self/uid_map       \
  && echo "Please run under buildah unshare"  \
  && exit
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current buildah release `buildah mount` blows up when not run a user namespace.

```
$ buildah mount
cannot mount using driver overlay in rootless mode. You need to run it in a `buildah unshare` session
$ echo $?
125
$ buildah -v
buildah version 1.17.0-dev (image-spec 1.0.1-dev, runtime-spec 1.0.2-dev)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question.